# Form sending error, Flask

Tags: python, forms, flask

There is form with two `<input type="submit">`. But when i'm sending it, second submit causes error.

*layout*:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('index') }}" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="add" value="Like">
    <input type="submit" name="remove" value="Dislike">
</form>
```

*main.py*:

```
...
if request.method == 'POST':
    if request.form['add']:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    elif request.form['remove']:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
...
```

First submit(add) works well, but second(remove)...:

> **Bad Request** The browser(or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.

How can i fix this error?

**UPD**:

It was pretty simple:
request.form returns ImmutableMultiDict:

```
... 
if 'Like' in request.form.values():
     ...
elif 'Dislike' in request.form.values():
     ...
```

Comment: Refer to this link: https://jjude.com/flask-errors/

Answer (score 90, accepted):

As @Blubber points out, the issue is that Flask raises an HTTP error when it fails to find a key in the `args` and `form` dictionaries.  What Flask assumes by default is that if you are asking for a particular key *and it's not there* then something got left out of the request and the entire request is invalid.

There are two other good ways to deal with your situation:

1. Use `request.form`'s `.get` method:

   ```
   if request.form.get('add', None) == "Like":
       # Like happened
   elif request.form.get('remove', None) == "Dislike":
       # Dislike happened
   ```
2. Use the same `name` attribute for both submit elements:

   ```
   <input type="submit" name="action" value="Like">
   <input type="submit" name="action" value="Dislike">

   # and in your code
   if request.form["action"] == "Like":
       # etc.
   ```

Comment: I was using "id" in the template and it was throwing the 400 bad request error.

<input type="submit" id="action" value="Like">

Then I changed that to "name" and the request is accepted now.

<input type="submit" name="action" value="Like">

Thank you

Comment: This behaviour is kind of unexpected. Would've at least hoped for a log line or a traceback.

Comment: @ffledgling There is a security concern if error messages are too informative. Still I'd have appreciated something less cryptic in the error logs. I keep relearning what 400 BAD REQUEST means in Flask.

Answer (score 4):

You should be checking whether or not the `'add'` and `'remove'` keys are in the `request.form` dict.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    if 'add' in request.form:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    elif 'remove' in request.form:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

When you click *Like* it doesn't fail because the first condition is met, and hence the second is never checked. But if the *Dislike* button is clicked, that first condition will thrown a `KeyError` exception because `request.form` doesn't contain a key named `'add'`.

Comment: There's not any other errors, although debug mode is on.
I've tried your variant, however there's an error again: 400 Bad Request.

Comment: I assume you are running Flask behind a proxy? Are you sure there is no exception in the terminal (or wherever you started your application)?

Comment: No, i'm not running Flask behind a proxy. I'v tried try/except block:
400: Bad Request. There's no any another exception in terminal.

I'v also tried to make two forms with one submit button in each, but the result is same: second submit causese 400 error.

Comment: There are no other errors in that situation. No traceback. Just that  "less useless" output.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `<input type="submit">` Use `<button type="submit">`. I have the same error as you and tried soo many solution but none of that work