# 400 Bad Request when hitting submit button in Flask

Tags: python, flask, request, submit

When I hit the submit button I get a 400 Bad Request error. It actually redirects to the '/' page, but it displays the error instead of the page.

**These two buttons are on the same page, but only the 'Add' button works.**

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2">
    <form role="form" method="POST" action="/">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success-register">Register</button>
    </form>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2">
      <form action="/add">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success-add">Add</button>
      </form><br class="visible-xs visible-sm">
</div>
```

**Root Route:**

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():

    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.form['items'] == 'items':
            return redirect(url_for('data'))

    return render_template('register.html')
```

**Route that the buttons are on:**

```
@app.route('/data', methods=['GET','POST'])
def data():

    deleted_items_list = []

    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.form['delete'] == 'delete':
            deleted_items = request.form.getlist('delete-check')
            for item in deleted_items:
                deleted_items_list.append(item.encode("utf-8"))
            for item in deleted_items_list:

                g.db = connect_db()

                g.db.execute('DELETE FROM yardsale WHERE Description = ?', (item,))

                g.db.commit()
                g.db.close()
                print("items were deleted")

    items = ["id"]
    g.db = connect_db()
    c = g.db.execute('select * from yardsale')
    items = [dict(id=row[0], description=row[1], seller=row[2], SP=row[3], MSP=row[4], SF=row[5], Notes=row[6]) for row in c.fetchall()]
    g.db.close()

    return render_template('data.html', items=items)
```

Comment: It might similar to the followings. Confirm this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552675/form-sending-error-flask

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19578613/posting-data-on-flask-via-form-is-giving-400-bad-request

Comment: Show us the code from your `/` route, that will show why the form submission doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry. Should have posted that originally.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access `request.form['items']` but this isn't defined anywhere in your form. You're most likely raising a `KeyError` with this code.

For this code to work you'll need to ensure you have an  in your form with the name `items`.

Alternatively, if you want the form submission to work even without the `items` input being present, you can change your code to something like this

```
    if request.form.get('items') == 'items':
```

As this won't raise a `KeyError` if the `items` input is not defined.

Comment: I could be misunderstanding, but I do not think this is my problem. The Register button (the one i'm having the issue with) is on the '/data' page not the '/' page. The 'items' form is for a button that is working on the '/' page.

Comment: Your form around the Register button currently has `action="/"` which means your `index` route will handle the submission of that form, not the `data` route.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're missing name attribute.