# Flask: Use URL Binding in URL For?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a form in my Flask website which I want to open to a certain page on submit however the link I want uses URL binding which doesn't seem to work well, I'll show you what I mean with the following code.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('topic/<topic>') }}">
```

I get a build error due to me using the URL `topic/<topic>` in my `url_for`.

Is there a way to work around this? The reason for this is because every time someone enters in data to the form, when submitted, I want the user to be redirected to the same page (`topic/<topic>`) but will an additional `/1`. I want the number to increase every time the form is submitted so the first time it is submitted I want the URL to be `topic/<topic>/1` then the second time `topic/<topic>/2` and so forth.

**Update 1:**

I tried Martijn Pieters method out with the

```
"url_for('topic', topic='sometopic')"
```

I didn't include the counter just yet. I also have the

```
@app.route('/topic/<topic>')
```

however when I submit the form the url states

> "/topic/topic=The+Fundamental+Ideas+in+Chemistry"

. Before I tried the method it states

> "/topic/The+Fundamental+Ideas+in+Chemistry".

Is there a way to remove the 'topic=' part from the url so it looks like it was before?

**Update 2:**

```
@app.route('/topic/<topic>')
def questions(topic):
    g.db = connectDB()
    query = 'SELECT question FROM questions WHERE topic=\"' + topic + '\"'
    cur = g.db.execute(query)
    questions = [dict(question=row[0]) for row in cur.fetchall()]
    question = questions[0]['question']
    g.db.close()
    return render_template('topic.html', topic=topic, subject='chemistry', question=question)
```

Comment: You need to define how you are counting form submissions. Does your view configuration actually accept that parameter? E.g. have you registered the `/topic/<topic>/<int:counter>` URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the **name** of the view, not the URL it listens to. Views can listen to multiple URLs.

You registered your view with:

```
@app.route('/topic/<topic>')
def questions(topic):
    # ...
```

so the view is registered with the name `questions`. You need to use `questions` as the endpoint for `url_for()`, providing a value for the `<topic>` URL parameter::

```
url_for('questions', topic='sometopic')
```

If you want to pass in additional parameters, you need to make sure your view can accept those:

```
@app.route('/topic/<topic>')
@app.route('/topic/<topic>/<int:counter>')
def questions(topic, counter=None):
    # ...
```

and use the extra parameter when building the URL:

```
url_for('questions', topic='sometopic', counter=some_counter)
```

You'll also have to think about what it means for someone to submit the form each time. You'll need some form of persistence to store that counter, like a database or a file, or simply a global variable (but that won't scale to multiple processes).

Comment: Thanks for you response, I tried your method out with the "url_for('topic', topic='sometopic')", I didn't include the counter just yet. I also have the @app.route('/topic/<topic>') however when I submit the form the url states "/topic/?topic=The+Fundamental+Ideas+in+Chemistry". Usually it states "/topic/The+Fundamental+Ideas+in+Chemistry". Is there a way to remove the 'topic=' part from the url?

Comment: @user2426062 can you please update your question to include your view? Flask is not recognising that you have such a registration.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, would you like me to update my original question you mean?

Comment: @user2426062: I don't see the view function (at least the signature). Are there no other registrations?

Comment: I've updated to show the entire view function of topic in case. What do you mean by registrations?

Comment: Your route is named "questions" not "topic", so you need to use `url_for('questions', topic='sometopic')`

Comment: @user2426062: Each `@app.route()` decorator registers another URL for a view. Your view endpoint is called `questions`, not `topic`; I adjusted my answer to fit your updated question.

Comment: I tried your method and got a 'bad request', any suggestions? (I'll update this to my question after)

Comment: @user2426062: that'd be a *new* problem; you are probably trying to access request parameters that are not present or the wrong type, see [What is the cause of the Bad Request Error when submitting form in Flask application?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14105452). Your original problem has been solved now though.

Comment: @user2426062: If you have a new problem that you cannot solve with information found on Stack Overflow or elsewhere, you can ask a new question. The Stack Overflow format doesn't lend itself to progressive new questions.