# Unable to pass data to a third form using Flask

Tags: python, html, flask, pass-data

I am able to pass data from one html form to a second html page using Flask. But when I try to pass the data from the second html page to a third html page, i get an error:

werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'binary'

I am basically trying to input binary numbers on the first html page, convert it to a decimal on the second html page, and then convert it to a hexadecimal number on the third page. Here is my Flask code:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST','GET'])
def input_binary():
    if request.method == "POST":
        binary = request.form["binary"]
        return redirect(url_for("show_decimal", bin=binary))
    else:
        return render_template("binary.html")

@app.route('/<bin>', methods=['POST','GET'])
def show_decimal(bin):
    if request.method == "POST":
        decimal = request.form["decimal"]
        return redirect(url_for("show_hex", dec = decimal))
    else:
        decimal = int(bin,2) 
        return render_template("decimal.html", dec=decimal)

@app.route('/<dec>', methods=['POST','GET'])
def show_hex(dec):
    hexadecimal_string = hex(int(dec))
    return render_template("hex.html", hex = hexadecimal_string)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

It seems like when i click submit on the second page again, it's trying to run the code from the `def input_binary` function and not the `def show_hex` function. Maybe it has to do with the submit button on the second page?

This is the html on the second html page:

```
<body>
    <p>{{dec}}</p>
    <form name="decimalNumber" action="." method="POST">
        <label>Input the decimal number</label>
        <input type="number" name="decimal">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: your html has no binary input. when you get value from dict, you should check whether key exists.

Comment: the binary input is on the first html page shown below:

Comment: ```
    <form name="binaryNumber" action="." method="POST">
        <label for="">Input a binary number</label>
        <input type="number" name="binary">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: Do you have another proxy server? I copy your code , run it, that's ok.

Answer (score 0):

- first, your input name "binary" may be conflicted with http protected keyname. try another name. you can see [What is the cause of the Bad Request Error when submitting form in Flask application?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14113958/15073910)