# How to respond with 400 in Django on `MultiValueDictKeyError`?

Tags: python, django, forms, http-status-codes

Coming from Flask, `request.args[key]` and `request.form[key]` [responds with 400](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552675/form-sending-error-flask) if the key doesn't exist. This has a nice property of [failing fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807241/what-does-the-expression-fail-early-mean-and-when-would-you-want-to-do-so).

In Django, `request.GET[key]` and `request.FORM[key]` raises `HttpResponseBadRequest` if the key doesn't exist, which causes your API to respond with a 500 status if unhandled. I've seen [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895588/django-multivaluedictkeyerror-error-how-do-i-deal-with-it) recommending `request.GET.get(key)`, but that inadvertently loosens the API contract that could allow client-side bugs to slip by (e.g. a query parameter typo, forgetting to include a param, etc).

I could manually check for required query params:

```
arg1 = request.POST.get('arg1')
if not arg1:
    raise HttpBadRequest('"arg1" was not provided.')

arg2 = request.POST.get('arg2')
if not arg2:
    raise HttpBadRequest('"arg1" was not provided.')

arg3 = request.POST.get('arg3')
if not arg3:
    raise HttpBadRequest('"arg3" was not provided.')
```

But that leaves a lot of room for error. (Did you notice the typo?)

I could manually handle `HttpResponseBadRequest`:

```
def my_view(request):
    try:
        arg1 = request.POST['arg1']
        arg2 = request.POST['arg2']
        arg3 = request.POST['arg3']
    except MultiValueDictKeyError as ex:
        raise HttpBadRequest('"{}" was not provided.'.format(ex))
```

But now you have an extra thing to remember when writing views.

Compare the above examples to Flask's equivalent:

```
arg1 = request.form['arg1']
arg2 = request.form['arg2']
arg3 = request.form['arg3']
```

How can I write the same thing in Django without extra boilerplate in my views and have it respond with `400` when a param is missing?

Answer (score 5):

This is exactly you should use [Django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/). They are the validation framework that checks the user input and returns errors when it is not valid.

(Note, it's not the accessing of the nonexistent key that raises BadRequest; it raises MultiValueDictKeyError, as one of your snippet notes, and if that is unhandled the response middleware will return BadRequest.)

Comment: Thanks! This seems overkill for simple JSON-based API views though. Are Django forms still used for that?