# TutorialsPoint - Flask – SQLAlchemy not working

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

I did all that was stated on tutorial point (**just copied and pasted**), but when I tried to add a student entry,i.e. ‘Add Student’ it gives

Bad Request
The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.

Please advise if there is anything wrong with the tutorial.

It failed at this line within def new(), in app.py:

```
 student = students(request.form['name'], request.form['city'], request.form['addr'], request.form['pin'])
```

Whoever is flagging this down. Note that it is the tutorial that is filled with **typos and wrong indentations**. I am only a student. Shut this down and I will learn nothing.

Ref: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_sqlalchemy.htm

```
from flask import Flask, request, flash, url_for, redirect, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///students.sqlite3'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "random string"

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Students(db.Model):
    id = db.Column('student_id', db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    city = db.Column(db.String(50))
    addr = db.Column(db.String(200)) 
    pin = db.Column(db.String(10))

    def __init__(self, name, city, addr,pin):
        self.name = name
        self.city = city
        self.addr = addr
        self.pin = pin

    @app.route('/')
    def show_all():
        return render_template('show_all.html', Students = Students.query.all() )

    @app.route('/new', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
    def new():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if not request.form['name'] or not request.form['city'] or not request.form['addr']:
                flash('Please enter all the fields', 'error')
        else:
            print "1";
            student = Students(request.form['name'], request.form['city'], request.form['addr'], request.form['pin'])

            print "1";
            db.session.add(student)
            print "1";
            db.session.commit()
            print "1";
            flash('Record was successfully added')
            print "=======>>>>>>>>>";
            return redirect(url_for('show_all'))
        return render_template('new.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    db.create_all()
    app.run(debug = True)
```

Comment: Please, help us understanding your issue here?...Post code, complete error message..etc..

Comment: The code is in the link.

Comment: @UrsaMajor .. No..post what you typed..!!. it's not the same thing ...May be you have a typo error, or something else...

Comment: I copied and pasted. It would be the same, if I were to copy and paste here.

Comment: The tutorial has problems. The author really has to correct it. Beginners trust and depends on the teachings.

Comment: i did. 

<form action = "{{ url_for('new') }}" method = "post">

Comment: yes, it is the same issue

Comment: I traced that there is a problem with `   student = students(request.form['name'], request.form['city'], request.form['addr'], request.form['pin'])`

Comment: I don't get any issue when running this apps, except for fixing indentation issue mentioned below...what python version are u using?...Did u install `flask-sqlalchemy`??...

Comment: @UrsaMajor its possible that you've mismatched the items in the dict sent to the server.

Comment: The tutorial is filled with typos and wrong indentations.

Comment: missing whitespace after `addr` edit `addr,pin` to `addr, pin)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tutorial has an indentation problem in the student class.
The constructor code should be indented one level so it becomes a method of the student class.

Corrected code:  (note the indent of "def **init**(self, name, city, addr,pin):" in the code below)

```
class students(db.Model):
   id = db.Column('student_id', db.Integer, primary_key = True)
   name = db.Column(db.String(100))
   city = db.Column(db.String(50))
   addr = db.Column(db.String(200)) 
   pin = db.Column(db.String(10))

   def __init__(self, name, city, addr,pin):
      self.name = name
      self.city = city
      self.addr = addr
      self.pin = pin
```

The reason is, if that indent is not there, python will not see this function as a constructor of the student class. So the constructor with the matching number of arguments is not found, resulting in the error.

Comment: Looks like there could be other problems as well.

Comment: Even the student object code is not indented properly, if you check it shows _E111 - indentation is not a multiple of four_ so the error arises from the request.form.

Comment: Could be, depending on how the code is copy/pasted into an editor. Make sure to use a python-aware IDE such as PyCharm or other: https://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratedDevelopmentEnvironments

Comment: The page on the link does show that the indentation is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out on the indentation. However, there are still other errors.

Comment: I traced that there is a problem with `   student = students(request.form['name'], request.form['city'], request.form['addr'], request.form['pin'])`

Comment: That is invoking the student constructor.  For me "add user" works fine, just changing the indentation mentioned above. Cross check all indentation: 4 spaces for each level as explained here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation

Answer (score 0):

It's not following the [class naming](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) convention. The student class should use [Camel case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase). Try this:

```
student = Students(request.form['name'], request.form['city'],
        request.form['addr'], request.form['pin'])
```

The SQLAlchemy model should also follow the same, Students not students.

```
class Students(db.Model):
    id = db.Column('student_id', db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    city = db.Column(db.String(50))  
    addr = db.Column(db.String(200))
    pin = db.Column(db.String(10))
```

**Edit**
Given Iron Fist's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38671408/tutorialspoint-flask-sqlalchemy-not-working/38671942?noredirect=1#comment64724357_38671408) that the same code is running okay for him, its very likely that there is a mistake or typo in your code for creating a new student object. Even if you have copy pasted the code, an error may occur when typing the code  assuming you did not use CTRL-V or when pasting it. According to the Flask docs:

> What happens if the key does not exist in the form attribute? In that case a special KeyError is raised. You can catch it like a standard KeyError but if you don’t do that, a HTTP 400 Bad Request error page is shown instead. So for many situations you don’t have to deal with that problem.

Therefore if @IronFist ran the same code without a problem, but for you its returning a bad response error which as explained above is as a result of a missing key in the form, then its most likely a mistake on the code you are running. Also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105452/what-is-the-cause-of-the-bad-request-error-when-submitting-form-in-flask-applica) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552675/form-sending-error-flask) they are similar to your question.

Comment: Not following the naming convention will not cause an error.

Comment: @Davy its possible he may have _Students_ in the class and _students_ while creating the new student or vice versa.

Comment: @UrsaMajor the bad request error means there is something wrong with your form dictionary, there is a mismatch or missing item in your `keys`.

Comment: I think the tutorial is filled with so much error that it is unusable. The author has been very irresponsible to misguide beginners like us.

Comment: I've edited my answer with links to similar questions, plus @IronFist ran the same code without a problem. Given the bad response error, there is a problem in the dict that contains the keys & args. Assuming you typed the same code and did not actually copy and paste, that is where the error originates from, you may have missed something while typing.