# post request error with flask

Tags: python, curl, flask

I'm trying to make a CRUD REST API with Flask en SQlALchemy. I'm making request with the curl command on the linux shell but I cant get it to work. If I open a python shell and add the things manually they get added to the database.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.</p>
```

```
@app.route('/create', methods = ['POST'])
def create():
    username = request.form['username']
    age = request.form['age']
    email = request.form['email']
```

```
curl -X POST -F 'username=Juliana' -F 'age=87' -F 'email=juliana@.com' http://localhost:5000/create
```

Comment: Please give a proper error description.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error. It works in my tests.

Comment: lol, thats the error, it's saying that my server didnt understand my curl request. I'm almost sure its something wrong with my curl request

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the cause of the Bad Request Error when submitting form in Flask application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105452/what-is-the-cause-of-the-bad-request-error-when-submitting-form-in-flask-applica)

Answer (score 0):

> the issue is that Flask raises an HTTP error when it fails to find a key in the args and form dictionaries. What Flask assumes by default is that if you are asking for a particular key and it's not there then something got left out of the request and the entire request is invalid.

check:

1. [What is the cause of the Bad Request Error when submitting form in Flask application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105452/what-is-the-cause-of-the-bad-request-error-when-submitting-form-in-flask-applica)
2. [Form sending error, Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552675/form-sending-error-flask)

change your `create` view to the following code and check output:

```
@app.route('/create', methods = ['POST'])
def create():
    username = request.form.get('username', '')
    age = request.form.get('age', '')
    email = request.form.get('email', '')
    print username, age, email

    # dbcreate = Profile(username, age, email)
    # db.session.add(dbcreate)
    # db.session.commit()
    # print 'User Created'
```